# Create a UITableView sectioned by Dates

Tags: iphone, uitableview

How does one create a UITableView sectioned by Date? And how would the dates of the objects be used when the tableview is setup?

Answer (score 3):

If you already know dates that you want to use for sections store them in an array as arrays. So in another words create an array for every date you want to act as a section. Then go through your customObjects and insert them into appropriate section array. When you have this use method `numberOfSectionsInTableView` to get the number of sections.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [datesArray count];
}
```

Then you will have to tell UITableDelegate how many rows you will need per section. To do that you use `numberOfRowsInSection`.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[datesArray objectAtIndex:section] count];
}
```

Then in the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` simply get customObject data for a cell from an appropriate section array.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomTableCell";
    static NSString *CellNib = @"UserCustomTableCell";

    UserCustomTableCell *cell = (UserCustomTableCell *)[table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellNib owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (UserCustomTableCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    MyObject *customObject = [[datesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] indexPath.row];

    //Setup your cell here
    cell.date.text = [customObject date];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a grouped UITableView with the date of each object as the sections of the table.

You would likely want to read your dates into an array, storing only the unique dates, and use that array count to set the number of sections in your table. Then match each date in the array with the objects in your data source that match that date when populating rows in each sections. (Unless your data is already sorted in your datasource by date).

numberOfSectionsInTableView would be based on the number of distinct dates in your date
numberOfRowsInSection would be based on the number of elements with each date

Use indexPath which would hold your section (Date) and row (objects) against your dictionary or other data source to get the data for the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.